# Fuelphp get post comments on same page logic

Tags: php, join, fuelphp

First I'm really new to fuelphp, you can down vote the question if needed.
My problem is that i made a facebook similar wall, and i don't really understand the comments logic.

So i tried to join my tables this way

```
static function get_stream()
    {
        $query = DB::select()->from('stream_post');
        $query->join('users_metadata');
        $query->on('stream_post.user_id', '=', 'users_metadata.user_id');
        $query->join('stream_comment');
        $query->on('stream_post.stream_id', '=', 'stream_comment.stream_id');
        $query->order_by('stream_post.stream_id', 'DESC');
        $result = $query->execute();
        if(count($result) > 0) {    
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                $data[] = $row;
            }

            return $data;
        }

    }
```

the problem with this is that, this only shows the stream posts what have comments, and doesn't show the others.

So can please someone give me a logic how to join the tables to show those post to what doesn't have a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
static function get_stream()
    {
        $query = DB::select()->from('stream_post');
        $query->join('users_metadata');
        $query->on('stream_post.user_id', '=', 'users_metadata.user_id');
        $query->join('stream_comment', 'RIGHT'); // The RIGHT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the right table, even if there are no matches in the left table.
        $query->on('stream_post.user_id', '=', 'stream_comment.user_id');
        $query->order_by('stream_post.stream_id', 'DESC');
        $result = $query->execute();
        if(count($result) > 0) {    
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                $data[] = $row;
            }

            return $data;
        }
}
```

**Edit:**
That query should work (when every `user_id` from `stream_post` has the same `user_id` in `users_metadata`. Just transfer this query to fuelphp (I didn't use it before).

```
SELECT *
FROM stream_post
RIGHT JOIN stream_comment
ON stream_post.stream_id = stream_comment.stream_id
JOIN users_metadata
ON stream_post.user_id = users_metadata.user_id
ORDER BY stream_post.stream_id DESC
```

Comment: sorry my bad edited the question, and tried your code, shows nothing

Comment: see my edit (you can also try to run this query in PHPmyAdmin to see what you get).

Comment: the problem with this when i change the query to left jouin it retunrs the stream post id null

Comment: looks like nothings workink, but thanks for your help will try to figure  it out

Comment: man thaks so much for your help, your code was right at the first time with left join, it was my bad, the stream post and stram comment had a same field name stream post id and the stream comment stream id overwitten the stream posts id, so sorry about that, and thanks for your help